# regular expression for decimal places

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to create a regexp that would make valid

```
11
11.1
11.11
```

But invalid

```
11.
11.111
```

However my regular expression

```
\\d+\\.?\\d{0,2}?
```

Allows `11.`.
How to update it to make `11.` invalid?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put the . and the following digits into an optional group and make the minimum length of the trailing digits 1

```
\\d+(\\.\\d{1,2})?
```

Answer (score 3):

Group the dot and the fractional part and make this group optional:

```
\\d+(?:\\.\\d{1,2})?
```

Comment: What is the purpose of `?:` ?

Comment: @vikingsteve, this denotes a [non-capturing group](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/regex/660/capture-groups/2155/backreferences-and-non-capturing-groups#t=201701241306401336622)

Comment: is a non-capturing group necessary here?

Comment: Since there is no requirement to extract the fractional part, we may save a little bit on capturing overhead.

Comment: I would add anchors for start and end of string since without them it matches, for example, `11` in `11.`.